# How can I select the features based on propetry

Tags: javascript, json

How can I select the features from the property attributes of the feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Array.protoype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Ok, it's not pretty but it works;)

1. Create a filter function

   ```
   function filterBy(element) {
     return
       element.properties.systemtime_start ==
       getMonthFromEpoch(element.properties.systemtime_start);
   }
   ```
2. Create a function to filter the month

   ```
   function getMonthFromEpoch(time) {
     var month = 'noMonthSet';
     var tMonth = new Date(time).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: 'long'});
     if (tMonth == 'January') {
       month = time;
     }
     return month
   }
   ```
3. Pass the part with the features of your object to the filter

   ```
   var filterd = yourObject.features.filter(filterBy)
   ```

This will return a new array with objects matching to systemstartTime 'January'

One more thing. I would change your naming. Use `system_time_start` instead of `system:time_start`. Otherwise you won't be able this property via JS

Comment: yes filtering is the way of doing. however, due to my limited knowledge of the javascript, I did not know how to pass the filtering functions in my case?

Comment: sorry for the terrible syntax highlighting. For some reason i can't get it to work with the editor